# iOS some devices not getting notifications even though they are enabled

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using FCM for notifications on both Android and iOS. When posting to FCM to send a message, it goes through and will send to some devices although, some will not get it even with them enabled.

This is what I'm sending to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

```
{
  "to": "TOKEN HERE",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
    "title": "Second Key",
    "body": "Test Body",
    "deepLink": "https://google.com",
    "sound": "default"
  },
  "data": {
    "title": "Test Title",
    "body": "Test Body",
    "deepLink": "https://google.com"
  }
}
```

This works and will show the notification on both iOS and Android but some devices won't get the notification.

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue now. iPhone 5s and 6 receive the notification, but iPhone 6s and 7s do not, but all are running the same app version, the same iOS version, and the iOS version has the same build numbers, so I don't understand what is going on. It happens from API send or from Console, send, some just don't get it...